# alto router doesn't route correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, altorouter

I've made the .htaccess file and that works, but the routing of alto router doesn't

```
<?php

require 'altorouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/rimaxxApi/');
$router->map('GET', '/', function(){

  echo 'It is working';
});

$match = $router->match();

// Here comes the new part, taken straight from the docs:

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}

?>
```

The path is in a subfolder

With this code I keep getting the "404" error, but I have the route defined.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$router->setBasePath('/rimaxxApi');`